# Changing variables from exec statement in imported module

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-import, multi-module

I'm trying to use a bash script to run multiple python scripts at once, and I modify python variables like amounts or min/max from the bash script (called MasterLoader) by passing in args like so:

```
A_Num=20

python A1.py "global AMOUNT; AMOUNT = $A_Num" &&
python A2.py &&
#More follows

$SHELL
```

And within A1 I have a function:

```
def take_args():
    for i in range(len(sys.argv)-1):
        exec(sys.argv[i+1])
```

Now, this works fine.  My issue came from when I implemented a module hosting all functions for every file (I had ~250 lines or more of redundant code each module) like so:

```
def take_args():
    for i in range(len(sys.argv)-1):
        exec(sys.argv[i+1])

def common_function1():
    #Code here
#More functions follow
```

I called this module functions, and now in A1 (Any of them really) I simply do:

```
from functions import *

def main()
    #<Variables here>

    take_args()
```

However, this no longer works, as the variable in A1 is not being changed.  My thinking is now it's running take_args() in functions and is changing that global AMOUNT?  Since the public function refactor I have a single function and no global variables, so I'd like to do this without using either of the solutions I can currently implement:

1. copying def take_args(): across every function and making all possible variables I'd want to adjust global
2. having to modify both MasterLoader's args that I pass and A1.py to pass the related variables to functions

If possible I'd like the solution to involve simply changing MasterLoader's args, like I had before.  Solution 2 doesn't work for me because I have ~60 scripts that I'd have to refactor if I wanted new variable changed, and solution 1 is clunky from a programming perspective (duplicate code, global variables)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "implemented a module hosting all functions for every file" and "A[N]" (or "A[N].py". Also you don't show the bash script you're using with this multiple-function module that's giving you problems.

Comment: Edited it.  I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence, it's MasterLoader, the first block of code.  I run that to execute all my scripts at once and it passes in the args as it runs them.

Comment: Clear example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You do **not** want to use `exec` like that. You have developed an insecure, buggy method of passing arguments to a program.

Comment: I can't see a different way of not having to declare args in the scripts themselves, and suddenly I'm back to manually re-factoring a whole bunch of scripts every new variable I want to modify.  If you can explain a proper way to do this (modify the python variables from the bash script without editing the python scripts themselves), I'd all ears, but I just can't see one with my level of experience.

Comment: Still don't really understand. However, perhaps you can pass `sys.argv` to `take_args()` as an argument instead of having it reference the module attribute directly itself. i.e. `def take_args(argv):...` and then `take_args(sys.argv)`. That way you be sure it's getting the current program arguments.

Comment: Ok, to break it down as simple as I can:  MasterLoader,sh runs, the first line it passes in an argument to A1, being "global AMOUNT; AMOUNT = $A_Num"  A1.py then runs, and the first thing it does is from functions.py import *.  It then runs take_args() <which was imported from functions.py>  This causes it to exec the argument, so it runs global AMOUNT; AMOUNT = 20.  Sadly, this doesn't actually change the global value AMOUNT in A1.py  And I don't know why.  It worked before when take_args() was declared in A1.py, and I didn't have functions.py at all. I don't want to revert and gain 10k lines